# Scala how to avoid using null?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and want to know whats the best way to avoid using null in Scala.How to refactor following logic :

```
 var nnode : Node = null
 if (i==str.length-1) {
     nnode = Node(ch,mutable.Map[Char,Node](), collection.mutable.Set(str))
 } else {
     nnode = Node(ch,mutable.Map[Char,Node](), collection.mutable.Set())
 }
 nnode...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the last parameter is the only one that is affected, they rest of the code only needs to be written once:

```
val set = if (i == str.length - 1) collection.mutable.Set(str) else collection.mutable.Set()
val nnode = Node(ch, mutable.Map[Char, Node](), set)
```

You could also avoid a `val` and put the calculation of `set` inside the `Node` constructor:

```
val nnode = Node(
  ch,
  mutable.Map[Char, Node](),
  if (i == str.length - 1) collection.mutable.Set(str) else collection.mutable.Set()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nnode: Node = 
  if (i == str.length - 1) Node(ch, new mutable.Map[Char, Node](), mutable.Set(str))
  else Node(ch, new mutable.Map[Char, Node](), mutable.Set.empty)
```

Comment: you can also use val